# OpenCL - lightweight enough for static linking?

Tags: static-libraries, opencl, distributed-computing, dynamic-linking

I'm looking to use the OpenCL library for a program that needs to be distributed to many (1000s) machines. Because size of the program is a concern, I wanted to know if statically linking the OpenCL library would make sense. Is the OpenCL lightweight enough for this application?

Comment: mmm, I don't think OpenCL is lightweigth at all. What about the graphic drivers ? Are all the machines the same ?

Comment: Well, the machines are highly heterogeneous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not really statically link OpenCL however you can statically link the OpenCL ICD (Installable Client Driver). ICD will than dynamically load all OpenCL platforms locally available.

ICD implementation is OS dependent but works quite well and is supported by major vendors SDK (AMD, NVIDIA, Intel, etc.). Thanks to ICD you can compile a binary with AMD SDK but the same binary will work well with NVIDIA and Intel OpenCL.

ICD should be quite useful for your problem too because the binaries will include only a very little amount of code (i.e. only the code to dynamically load the local OpenCL platforms).

Comment: What is the ICD? Is it header files? is it a lib? I can't seem to find a place to obtain it by googling

Comment: ICD (Installable Client Driver: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt). You have only to use one of the major vendor SDKs (like the one available from AMD, NVIDIA or Intel) to use this mechanic and obtain the benefits listed above.